# Gitlab - CI - Timeout set to 5h - but get Error: "Execution took longer than 3h0m0s seconds"

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

We use CI in Gitlab (shared runners)

- get error: ERROR: Job failed: execution took longer than 3h0m0s seconds

But I set the time to 5 hours according to the instructions.
Is there a catch in how it should behave?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can configure the runner time out if you're running a self-hosted instance of GitLab.

> We use CI in Gitlab (shared runners)

However, if you're using shared runners on GitLab.com,

> jobs handled by shared runners on GitLab.com (`shared-runners-manager-X.gitlab.com`) **time out after 3 hours**, regardless of the timeout configured in a project.

Reference: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/saas/linux_saas_runner.html